# $\overline{A\cdot B}=\overline{A}\cdot\overline{B}$ for $A,B\subseteq\Bbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $A$ is a closed set in $\Bbb R$ and $B$ a compact set in $\Bbb R$, let $A\cdot B=\{a\cdot b:a \in A,b\in B\}$.

**Question:** Is $\overline{A\cdot B}=\overline{A}\cdot\overline{B}$?

Note: $\overline{A}$ is the closure of set $A$.

Comment: What have you tried? Is anything in particular bothering you about this question?

Comment: Because $A,B$ are closed we have to show if $cl(AB)=AB$ or if $AB$ is closed. Check what happens for $A=\Bbb N$ and $B=[0,1]$ knowing that $\Bbb N$ has no upper bound

Comment: if $ A=\mathbb{N} $ and $ B=[0,1]$  , is $A.B=\cup_{i \in N} [0,i]$?

Comment: @giancarlo: Yes, in that case $$A\cdot B=\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}[0,i]=[,\to)\;,$$ the set of all non-negative real numbers. This is fine, since it’s a closed set.

Comment: Please don't repost questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553173/let-a-b-subseteq-mathbbr-if-a-is-closed-and-b-is-compact-is-a-cdot/554858#554858

Comment: I find the closure of this question quite appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\mathbb{N}$ and $B=\{\frac{1}{n}:n \in \mathbb{N} \}\cup\{0 \}$ , then A is closed and B is compact but $A.B$ is no closed because $\sqrt{2}$ is an adherent point , and $\sqrt{2} \notin A.B$ .